# Redundant input in cin

Tags: c++, input, cin

What happens with the redundant input we give to a program? Suppose you want to read an integer in variable `a` from the standard input, but you enter five space separated integers. The terminal gives the first line of input to the program. `a` is filled with the first integer. Now, what happens to the other input you supplied? Can you get acces to it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read multiple inputs:

```
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
int c;
cin >> c;
```

Or, you can simply ignore any extra input, and it will be discarded when the program exits.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other 4 integers are left in the stream. So if you have more cins later you can get them